# cannot see bold and italic char in xelatex

Tags: xetex, bold, italic, xepersian

I am writing a Persian article using *Xelatex* typesetting and the *xepersian* package. My problem is that I cannot see characters get **bold** or *italic* using `textbf` and `textit` respectively.
This is my sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} 
\begin{document}
\section{مقدمه}
\subsection{فرمول بندی مساله}
در این بخش به فرمول بندی مدل زمان -‍ پیوسته ی انتشار برای داده ی مشخص و سپس‌،  راست نمایی آن پرداخته می شود.
\subsubsection{داده ی مساله }
در این پایان نامه، چندین موج انتشار برروی تعداد ثابتی از
\textbf{\textit{N}}


 گره در نظر گرفته شده است.


\end{document}
```

what shall I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which font do you use? (If I try to run your code, I get an error message, "You have not specified any font for the main Persian text".)

Comment: @Mico thanks. I did not mention any font in my script. By the way, I did not use fontspec applications in my code, thus u can omit it.

Comment: @Mico I am compiling it with Texworks.

Comment: the defult font in Texworks is `MS Shell Dlg 2`

Comment: You need to define text font with `\settextfont{name_of_font}`.

Comment: thanks @salimbou I set the font and the problem is solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in comments